# AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() cause deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, uwp

I'm writing a application with a critical region.

And I decide to use AutoResetEvent to achieve mutual exclusion.
Here's the code

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        private AutoResetEvent lock = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        private aync Task CriticalRegion()
        {
            Dosomething();
        }


        public async Task Button_Click()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Entering Button_Click");
            lock.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                await CriticalRegion();
            }
            finally
            {
                lock.Set();
                Debug.WriteLine("Leaving Button_Click");

            }
        }

    }
```

I have a button whose click event calls the `Button_Click()` method

It works normally. But, if I'm quick enough to click the button for another time before the first call to `Button_Click()` completes, the whole app stops responding.

In the Debug window I find something like this

```
Entering Button_Click
Entering Button_Click
```

Looks like the method never completes.

I struggled a bit and find that if I change `lock.WaitOne();` to

```
   if (!sync.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
   {
       return;
   }
```

In this case my app is able to avoid the deadlock,but I don't know why it works.

I only know about the IPC from my OS course and the `async` and `await` pattern in C#, and I'm not so familiar with the thread in .Net world.

I really want to understand what's really going on behind the scenes.
Thanks for any replys ;)

Comment: The posted snippet is inadequate to demonstrate the deadlock.  But that you are doing it wrong is evident, focus a bit on the class name.  It is autoreset *event*.  Events are used for signaling, a "critical region" requires mutual exclusion.  Which requires a mutex, most easily done in C# with the `lock` keyword.  Using a lock on the UI thread is formally illegal, practically too likely to cause deadlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a deadlock because `WaitOne` is blocking the main thread (button click handler is executed on the main thread), while you haven't called [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when calling `await`, which means that it tries to run the code which is after `await` on the main thread, even if it's blocked, which would causes a deadlock.

I suggest reading [this post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for a thorougher explanation of the dead lock situation.

For your code, I would suggest putting the lock deeper, probably within the async Task, and trying to use a more suitable pattern for locking, preferably, the [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), because using `Event` objects is awkward for mutual exclusion, as Hans stated in the comment.

Comment: Thanks ,those posts really helped a lot.Another question,my critical region actually contains some `await` keyword.So what about use  `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` ?

Comment: It seems that `SemaphoreSlim` is really the prefered approach with async locking.

Answer (score 1):

[**`AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx) will block infinitely until you call [**`AutoResetEvent.Set()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx), which you never seem to do except for *after* the `WaitOne()` call.

Quoting the `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` documentation:

> Blocks the current thread *until the current WaitHandle receives a signal*.

Comment: You are right, but he describes a more race-condition deadlock rather than a 100% one, so I think my explanation suits better in this case.